# Can't bind to 'authorize' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular, angular8

On a `HeaderComponent` I am using an `authorize` directive:

```
<li *authorize="'SignedIn'"><button (click)="signIn()">Sign In</button></li>
```

But I get the error:

```
Can't bind to 'authorize' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.
```

The `HeaderComponent` is added to a HeaderModule:

```
@NgModule({  
  declarations: [    
    HeaderComponent
  ],  
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PopupModule
  ],  
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent
  ]
})
```

The `HeaderModule` and the `AuthorizeDirective` are added to a `SharedModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ 
    AuthorizeDirective
  ],    
  imports: [ 
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [ 
    HeaderModule,
    AuthorizeDirective
  ]
})
```

And the `SharedModule` is added to `AppModule`.

What am I missing?

The authorize directive is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[authorize]'
})

export class AuthorizeDirective implements OnInit {

  private notifier: Subscription;

  requirement: Requirement;
  id: number;

  @Input() set authorize(requirement: string) {
    this.requirement = Requirement[requirement];
  }

  @Input() set authorizeId(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  ngOnInit() { 

  }

}
```

Comment: Something is up with your module definitions. The directive is declared in the SharedModule, but you are using it in a separate module that doesn't import it.

Comment: @Rich Yes, the Module where I am using it, HeaderModule, is being added to SharedModule. Wouldn't this be enough?

Comment: I am declaring the directive in SharedModule that I import in other modules so that they can use those Shared features. But HeaderModule is one of the Shared features. If I import SharedModule to HeaderModule as I do in other Modules that are not part of SharedModule then I get a circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `HeaderModule` is a child of `SharedModule`, you'll need to re-think some of your design. You cannot import the directive from `SharedModule` (parent) to `HeaderModule` (child). You can make `HeaderModule` a module independent of `SharedModule`, or you can create some other common module that holds `AuthorizeDirective`.

Answer (score 0):

I think authorize is `Input`  so you can use authorize like that

```
<li [authorize]="'SignedIn'"><button (click)="signIn()">Sign In</button></li>
```

Comment: I am using it as *authorize in other modules that import SharedModule and it is working fine. The problem is when I try to use it in a Module, HeaderModule, that is exported in SharedModule